# Silverlight 2 ChildWindow - how to change the manner of popping up?

Tags: silverlight-3.0, childwindow

I like ChildWindow in Silverlight 3 but I don't like the manner it appears on the screen. It appears too quick and even irritates the eyes.
Maybe does someone know how to change this manner, make it softer and maybe slower?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.childwindow%28VS.95%29.aspx it would appear that you can change the visual behaviour of the ChildWindow:

> To change the visual structure and
> visual behavior of a ChildWindow, copy
> and modify its default style and
> template.

However, I cannot guarentee that the popup speed is part of that, but it might just be worth exploring.